# Creating a scene graph / hierarchy using an entity component system

Tags: scenegraph, entity-component-system

I do not seem to find any good resources on how to organize entities from an ecs into a scene graph / hierarchical structure e.g. for a 3D editor.

Im talking about something like:

```
-root
  -player
    -left-arm
    -right-arm
  -tree
    -branch
```

Could you give me a design example or maybe link some resource that explains how I could achieve this?

Comment: Asking for external resources is off-topic on SO unfortunately. What have you tried?  I would imagine a straightforward `parentComponent` / `childComponents` approach would work.

Comment: To get a tree structure out of an ECS, you have to put some information of how nodes are linked together into some of the components. For example, you could make a component like `struct Node { std::vector<ID> children; }`, add that component to entities that can have child elements, and fill the vector with the entity IDs of those children.